How can I not show mpf.plot() in FastAPI?
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from fastapi.responses import *
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi import APIRouter
import mplfinance as mpf
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
from PIL import Image
from pathlib import Path

show(block=False)

router = APIRouter(
    prefix="/chart",
    tags=["chart"]

)

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


@router.get("/mpf/{name}")
def mpf_chart(name: str):
    ticker = yf.Ticker(name)
    df = ticker.history(ticker, interval='1d', auto_adjust=True, start='2023-01-01')
    fig = mpf.plot(df, type='line', volume=True, returnfig=True)
    fig.save_as('mpf.png')
    img = Path('mpf.png')

    return img

I want to save mpf.plot() as Image file and show when I access /chart/mpf/{name}, but there are error when i access /mpf/{name}.
I am begginer programmer so I really need your help. please give me any help.
Thank you.

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/mplfinance/plotting.py:476: UserWarning:

Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow should only be instantiated on the main thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001938ceccc __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001933b6788 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001938f3c48 _CFBundleGetValueForInfoKey + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x00000001970c1294 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 188
    4   AppKit                              0x00000001970c11cc -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 48
    5   _macosx.cpython-311-darwin.so       0x00000001338bd1c8 -[Window initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:withManager:] + 68
    6   _macosx.cpython-311-darwin.so       0x00000001338bff80 FigureManager_init + 240
    7   python3.11                          0x00000001041d8900 wrap_init + 20
    8   python3.11                          0x000000010416a23c wrapperdescr_call + 440
    9   python3.11                          0x000000010415c4ec _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 332
    10  python3.11                          0x000000010425e83c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
    11  python3.11                          0x0000000104262e18 _PyEval_Vector + 184
    12  python3.11                          0x000000010415c758 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 320
    13  python3.11                          0x000000010415d5e8 _PyObject_Call_Prepend + 176
    14  python3.11                          0x00000001041d8804 slot_tp_init + 196
    15  python3.11                          0x00000001041d0dfc type_call + 464
    16  python3.11                          0x000000010415c4ec _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 332
    17  python3.11                          0x000000010425e83c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 46152
    18  python3.11                          0x0000000104262e18 _PyEval_Vector + 184
    19  python3.11                          0x000000010415ffac method_vectorcall + 172
    20  python3.11                          0x000000010415cc60 _PyVectorcall_Call + 132
    21  python3.11                          0x0000000104260b6c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 55160
    22  python3.11                          0x0000000104262e18 _PyEval_Vector + 184
    23  python3.11                          0x000000010415cc60 _PyVectorcall_Call + 132
    24  python3.11                          0x0000000104260b6c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 55160
    25  python3.11                          0x0000000104262e18 _PyEval_Vector + 184
    26  python3.11                          0x000000010415cc60 _PyVectorcall_Call + 132
    27  python3.11                          0x000000010434c160 partial_call + 152
    28  python3.11                          0x000000010415c4ec _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 332
    29  python3.11                          0x0000000104281ae4 context_run + 348
    30  python3.11                          0x00000001041b4cc4 cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL_KEYWORDS + 168
    31  python3.11                          0x0000000104260b6c _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 55160
    32  python3.11                          0x0000000104262e18 _PyEval_Vector + 184
    33  python3.11                          0x0000000104160058 method_vectorcall + 344
    34  python3.11                          0x0000000104344b48 thread_run + 264
    35  python3.11                          0x00000001042ccdd4 pythread_wrapper + 48
    36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019377af94 _pthread_start + 136
    37  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000193775d34 thread_start + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException

I want to save mpf.plot() as Image file and show when I access /chart/mpf/{name}, but there are error when i access /mpf/{name}.
I am begginer programmer so I really need your help. please give me any help.
Thank you.
